# How to have multiple transform like 1 normal one and 1 in keyframe animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I want to have multiple transform like this, transform rotate in keyframe and transform scale not inside keyframe. But its not working as I expected. Any suggestion?

```
@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

#tree1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: wave 3s infinite linear;
    transform: scale(0.7);
}

#tree2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: wave 3s infinite linear;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: You'd have to combine the scale and rotate in one transform rule, however you can also use the scale property and the rotate property indepdendently of each other by using scale: and rotate: as opposed to transform: scale() rotate(); See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/r/rotate/ and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scale/

Comment: Thank you so much, i didnt know u can scale/rotate without transform

Comment: That's why we have Stack Overflow . Good luck with the project.